# Programmatically login to third party website and update page values by directly posting updated values to the form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck at programmatically posting data on the third party website page. I am authorize user of that website (I am registered user.)

In short

Step 1 – I need to create http request to get Login page

Step 2 – I need to pass the username and password

Step 3 – I need to create request for Profile page

Step 4 – I need to update few values on the page and submit the page

The third party website is build using ASP.net, I want to do all above steps programmatically using C#.

I am able to do using WATIN or WebDriver but I want to do it programmatically like directly fire POST request on the page.

I tried various options like 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(VS.80).aspx ,

Also used fiddler tool to compare my request browser request v/s my application request , they are same.

Also used Using **BrowserSession** and **HtmlAgilityPack**  from [Rohit Agerwals](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.in/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html)

No success, can anyone tired anything similar to this?

Comment: What was your problem exactly with the webrequest? It sounds like what you need ... also, have you given a look at the HttpClient? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: main problem, I am not able to login to the website, i fail at step 2- It does't login to the system. I got error as invalid username and password, but same username password work for web-driver or normal process using browser